# How do I get a second-degree equation that is tangent to the straight line?

Tags: fitting

How do I get a second-degree equation that is tangent to the straight line?

```
pix1=65;pix2=151;pix3=1215;fr1=0;fr2=5;fr3=59;
dist1=pix2-pix1;dist2=pix3-pix1
data1={{fr1,pix1},{fr2,pix2}}
eq1=Fit[data1,{1,x,x^2},x]
Plot[eq1,{x,fr1,fr2}]
eq1/.x->fr1
data2={{fr2,pix2},{fr3,pix3}}
eq2= Fit[data2, {1, x}, x]
Plot[eq2,{x,fr2,fr3}]
eq2/.x->fr3
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completely clear what the problem is, but I infer from the code that it is probably that the parabola should pass through $(0, 65)$ and $(5, 151)$ and have a slope at $x=5$ equal to the slope of the line through $(5, 151)$ and $(59, 1215)$.

Then here is the standard Calc. I method of solution:

```
form = a x^2 + b x + c;
Solve[{
  form == 65 /. x -> 0,                              (* pass thru (0, 65) *)
  form == 151 /. x -> 5,                             (* pass thru (5, 151) *)
  D[form, x] == (1215 - 151)/(59 - 5) /. x -> 5},    (* slope at x = 5 *)
 {a, b, c}]
(*  {{a -> 338/675, b -> 1984/135, c -> 65}}  *)

quad = form /. First[%]
(*  65 + (1984 x)/135 + (338 x^2)/675  *)

Plot[quad, {x, 0, 59},
 Mesh -> {{5}}, MeshShading -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 59.5}, {0, 1220}},
 Epilog -> {
   Red, AbsoluteThickness[1.6], Line[{{5, 151}, {59, 1215}}],
   Black, Point[{{0, 65}, {5, 151}, {59, 1215}}]
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Now your answer was beyond my expectation....

Comment: @LCarvalho Thanks, and thanks for the accept.  I just realized that I had eliminated `x` manually from the system and we could use `Solve` instead of `SolveAlways`.  It's not a big difference, but it seems better this way to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
pix1 = 65; pix2 = 151; pix3 = 1215;
fr1 = 0; fr2 = 5; fr3 = 59;
eq2 = Expand[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{fr2, pix2}, {fr3, pix3}}, x]];
eq1 = Expand[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{fr2, pix2, D[eq2, x]}, {fr1, pix1}}, x]];
Show[Plot[eq1, {x, fr1, fr2}], Plot[eq2, {x, fr2, fr3}], PlotRange -> All]
```

has $C^1$ continuity

Answer (score 2):

If we plot the points

```
pts = {{0, 65}, {5, 151}, {59, 1215}}
```

we get what is *seemingly* a straight line:

```
ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thin, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

*returns*

[image]

Appearances can be deceiving. Careful inspection reveals a slight kink at `x=5`.

Estimating a linear model on the data and inspecting the fitted values

```
lmf = LinearModelFit[pts, {1, x}, x];

lmf["Function"][Part[pts, All, 1]]
```

returns

> ```
> {59.3158, 157.211, 1214.47}
> ```

which is *not* a perfect fit.

Estimating a *quadratic* model on the data produces a perfect fit:

Evaluating

```
lmf = LinearModelFit[pts, {1, x, x^2}, x];

lmf["Function"][Part[pts, All, 1]]
```

returns

> ```
> {65., 151., 1215.}
> ```

The estimated quadratic function is

```
lmf["Function"][x]
```

> ```
> 65. + 16.9878 x + 0.0424357 x^2
> ```

The *slope* of the *fitted quadratic* function is

```
slp[x_] = D[lmf["Function"][x], {x, 1}]
```

> ```
> 16.9878 + 0.0848713 x
> ```

and at `x=5`, `slp[5]` evaluates to

> ```
> 17.4122
> ```

Now, a straight line eg `a+bx` is tangent to a curve at some point `x0`, if the line evaluated at `x=x0` is equal to `y0` ie the value of the curve at `x0` *and* both the line and the curve share the same slope at `x0`.

With these considerations in mind,

```
With[{x0 = pts[[2, 1]], y0 = pts[[2, 2]]},
  tan[x_] = a + b x /. First[
   Solve[{y0 == a + b x0, b == slp[x0]}, {a, b}]]
]
```

returns the tangent line to the fitted quadratic curve at point `{5, 151}`

> ```
> 63.9391 + 17.4122 x$
> ```

(I'm not sure why we get `x$`-a temporary symbol- instead of `x`-a global symbol, but that does not interfere with calculations).

Evaluating the tangent at all the given x-coordinates and plotting, produces

```
tnpts = {x, tan[x]} /. Transpose[{Thread[x -> Part[pts, All, 1]]}]

ListPlot[{pts, tnpts}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thin, Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts]}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 63.9391}, {5, 151.}, {59, 1091.26}}
> ```

and

[image]

respectively.

In short, *a* tangent curve of line `tan[x]` (= `63.9391 + 17.4122 x`) at point `{5, 151}` is the fitted quadratic polynomial `lmf["Function"][x]` (= `65. + 16.9878 x + 0.0424357 x^2`).

---

**code**

```
pts = {{0, 65}, {5, 151}, {59, 1215}}
ListPlot[pts, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thin, Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts]}]

(* the linear model fit *)
lmf = LinearModelFit[pts, {1, x}, x];
lmf["Function"][Part[pts, All, 1]]

(* the quadratic model fit *)
lmf = LinearModelFit[pts, {1, x, x^2}, x];
lmf["Function"][Part[pts, All, 1]]


slp[x_] = D[lmf["Function"][x], {x, 1}]

With[{x0 = pts[[2, 1]], y0 = pts[[2, 2]]},
  tan[x_] = a + b x /. First[
   Solve[{y0 == a + b x0, b == slp[x0]}, {a, b}]]
]

tnpts = {x, tan[x]} /. Transpose[{Thread[x -> Part[pts, All, 1]]}]

ListPlot[{pts, tnpts}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thin, Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts]}]
```